# Forge Data Visualization not working on Revit rooms [ITA]

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed the tutorials from the Forge Data Visualization extension documentation: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/ on a Revit file. I used the *generateMasterViews* option to translate the model and I can see the Rooms on the viewer, however I have problems coloring the surfaces of the floors: it seems that the *ModelStructureInfo* has no rooms.
The result of the *ModelStructureInfo* on the viewer.model is:

```
t {model: d, rooms: null}
```

Here is my code, I added the ITA localized versions of Rooms as 3rd parameter ("Locali"):

```js
const dataVizExtn = await this.viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
// Model Structure Info
let viewerDocument = this.viewer.model.getDocumentNode().getDocument();
const aecModelData = await viewerDocument.downloadAecModelData();
let levelsExt;
if (aecModelData) {
  levelsExt = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension", {
    doNotCreateUI: true
  });
}
// get FloorInfo
const floorData = levelsExt.floorSelector.floorData;
const floor = floorData[2];
levelsExt.floorSelector.selectFloor(floor.index, true);
const model = this.viewer.model;
const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model);
let levelRoomsMap = await structureInfo.getLevelRoomsMap();
let rooms = levelRoomsMap.getRoomsOnLevel("2 - P2", false);
// Generates `SurfaceShadingData` after assigning each device to a room (Rooms--> Locali).
const shadingData = await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices, undefined, "Locali");
// Use the resulting shading data to generate heatmap from.
await dataVizExtn.setupSurfaceShading(model, shadingData, {
  type: "PlanarHeatmap",
  placePosition: "min",
  usingSlicing: true,
});
// Register a few color stops for sensor values in range [0.0, 1.0]
const sensorType = "Temperature";
const sensorColors = [0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000];
dataVizExtn.registerSurfaceShadingColors(sensorType, sensorColors);
// Function that provides a [0,1] value for the planar heatmap
function getSensorValue(surfaceShadingPoint, sensorType, pointData) {
  const { x, y } = pointData;
  const sensorValue = computeSensorValue(x, y);
  return clamp(sensorValue, 0.0, 1.0);
}

const sensorType = "Temperature";
dataVizExtn.renderSurfaceShading(floor.name, sensorType, getSensorValue);
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there something else to do when using a different localization?

Here is a snapshot of what I get from the console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which viewer version you're using? There was an issue causing `ModelStructureInfo` cannot produce the correct `LevelRoomsMap`, but it gets fixed now. Please use `v7.43.0` and try again. Here is the snapshot of my test:

[image]

BTW, if you see `t {model: d, rooms: null}` while constructing the `ModelStructureInfo`, it's alright, since the room data will be produced after you called `ModelStructureInfo#getLevelRoomsMap` or `ModelStructureInfo#getRoomList`.

Comment: I'm using the last v.7.43.0. I edited the question and add my snapshot: I get an empty array for the roomlist

Comment: @duffra Could you share a non-confidential reproducible model demonstrating this issue to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` for our investigation?

Comment: I've just send by mail a very basic file for testing. Thanks

Comment: Posted by @user17356139: "The same thing happens to me. I get array 0 and there are no rooms. How was the problem solved?"

Comment: @Artem Could you also share a non-confidential reproducible model demonstrating this issue to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com for our investigation?

Comment: Yep, I asked the user17365139 to request the helpdesk. He seems is not able to post   comments.

Comment: Cool, thank you. See you in the Forge Help system then. :)