# ModelStructureInfo(Forge Data Visualization) doesn't work

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am creating a heat map using the page below as a reference.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/heatmap/create_heatmap_for_rooms/
However, the result of “ModelStructureInfo” is {model: Model, rooms: null}.
Therefore, all subsequent calculations do not work.

This is a similar question to the previous question below.
[Forge Data Visualization not working on Revit rooms [ITA]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544918/forge-data-visualization-not-working-on-revit-rooms-ita/67600112#67600112)
But, the conclusion is not stated.

I would like to know the solution to this matter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In [translation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/) under Case 6 - Input file type is RVT: mention generateMasterViews under output-> advanced as true.
Then get the room using:

```
NOP_VIEWER.search('Revit Rooms', ids => { roomids=ids }, err => { console.error(err); }, ['Category'], { searchHidden: true });
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take your advice into consideration and work on it.

Comment: I have written a blog, for this use case, please take a look: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/no-room-information-revit-file-when-working-dataviz-extension-viewer

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood how to do it.. I will try this approach.